# How can I reconnect to device after disconnecting in Core Bluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

In Core Bluetooth, after connecting to a device, I turn off the device and the device is disconnected. But when I turn on the device again, there is no `didDiscoverPeripheral` called again. How can I reconnect to the device again?

Comment: how you disconnect the device from peripheral?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you disconnect a device with `cancelPeripheralConnection` the `didDisconnectPeripheral` delegate method will be invoked. However from iOS 6.0 the device remains connected for about 40-50 seconds (or more), so no `didDiscoverPeripheral` will be invoked in that timeframe. If you want to "discover" it again just call the `retrieveConnectedPeripherals` method and you will get the reference in `didRetrieveConnectedPeripherals`.

However, the best solution is to save the device's UUID and use that to reconnect with the `retrievePeripherals` method. This will invoke `didRetrievePeripherals` and you can reconnect with `connectPeripheral`. This is the fastest way to reconnect to a device, no scanning is required in this case.

Comment: I am looking for the same with the EAAccessory Framework. Is it possible? If so can anyone direct me the "how to"? Thanks in advance...:)

Answer (score 4):

When you do a scan with `scanForPeripheralsWithServices`, it will normally only notify you once for a particular device address.  You can change this to report duplicates by specifying the option `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey`.  Or you can have your app detect that the other device disconnected using a timeout, and restart your scan.

Answer (score 3):

@Andras gave me the right path, but his answer is not complete anymore since iOS7.

The best way to reconnect to a previous device is to use the `retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers:)` method.

This method does not call a delegate, but directly returns you a list of `Peripheral`s, corresponding to the list of `UUID` passed in parameters.

```
if let peripheral = self.centralManager.retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers: [uuid]).first {
    self.peripheral = peripheral // <-- super important
    self.centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
}
```

Please check the "super important" line of the above code: The method `connect(_:option:)` does not retain the peripheral, and if you don't do it yourself, the connection will always fail without any callback since the peripheral objet will be destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

In CoreBluetooth all management is done by application layer.
In your case, what I would do it is to listen for disconnect event than in same event, reconnect the peripheral.
The connection method is an inexpensive one and assure you to reconnect to your device when it is back in range.

Note that if you explicitly disconnect the device, you received the same disconnect event, but you haven't to call the reconnect method.