# Swift 3 arduino Uno HM-10 Ble - Notifications on iphone

Tags: ios, swift3, arduino, notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have made an application for ios which connects to BLE(HM-10 on Arduino uno). There are temp, light and moisture sensor connected to the Arduino. The problem is that, the iPhone displays the data same as it displays the data on Arduino serial display. Whereas I want to have the temp sensors data to be displayed when I click on a "temperature button" and same for every other sensor. other thing I cant figure out is that I want the notifications if the app is not running in case temp. goes down by certain point. How should I do it

Please help!!

Here is the Arduino code(is it possible to print data in one line rather than it printing again and again in new line)

```
int sensePin = A1;  //This is the Arduino Pin that will control Relay #1
int sensorValue = 0;    //The variable we will use to store the sensor input
//int sensePin = A0;  //This is the Arduino Pin that will control Relay #1
int sensorInput;    //The variable we will use to store the sensor input
double temp; 


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600); //Start the Serial Port at 9600 baud (default)

}
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly: 
  sensorValue = analogRead(A1);    //read the analog sensor and store it

  sensorInput = analogRead(A0);    //read the analog sensor and store it
  temp = (double)sensorInput / 1024;       //find percentage of input reading
  temp = temp * 5;                 //multiply by 5V to get voltage
  temp = temp - 0.5;               //Subtract the offset 
  temp = temp * 100;               //Convert to degrees 


  if (temp > 28 ) {
   Serial.print("Current Temp is hot i.e.: ");
   Serial.println(temp);
  }

  else if (temp < 28) {
    Serial.print("Current Temp is cold i.e.: ");
    Serial.println(temp);
  }
   else{
    Serial.print("Current Temp: ");
    Serial.println(temp);
    }

if (sensorValue > 70 ) {
   Serial.print("Current Light is high i.e.: ");
   Serial.println(sensorValue);
  }

  else if (sensorValue < 60) {
    Serial.print("Current Light is low i.e.: ");
    Serial.println(sensorValue);
  }
   else{
    Serial.print("Light seems good: ");
    Serial.println(sensorValue);
    }


  //Serial.print("Current Temp: ");

  //Serial.println(temp);

  //Serial.print("Current Light: ");
  //Serial.println(sensorValue);

  //Serial.end();
  delay(10000);
}
```

Here is the Iphone code

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth
import QuartzCore

/// The option to add a \n or \r or \r\n to the end of the send message
enum MessageOption: Int {
    case noLineEnding,
         newline,
         carriageReturn,
         carriageReturnAndNewline
}

/// The option to add a \n to the end of the received message (to make it more readable)
enum ReceivedMessageOption: Int {
    case none,
         newline
}

final class SerialViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, BluetoothSerialDelegate {

//MARK: IBOutlets

    @IBOutlet weak var mainTextView: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var messageField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint! // used to move the textField up when the keyboard is present
    @IBOutlet weak var barButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var navItem: UINavigationItem!




//MARK: Functions

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // init serial
        serial = BluetoothSerial(delegate: self)

        // UI
        mainTextView.text = ""
        reloadView()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SerialViewController.reloadView), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "reloadStartViewController"), object: nil)

        // we want to be notified when the keyboard is shown (so we can move the textField up)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SerialViewController.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SerialViewController.keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

        // to dismiss the keyboard if the user taps outside the textField while editing
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SerialViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        // style the bottom UIView
        bottomView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        bottomView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: -1)
        bottomView.layer.shadowRadius = 0
        bottomView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        bottomView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor


    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        // animate the text field to stay above the keyboard
        var info = (notification as NSNotification).userInfo!
        let value = info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue
        let keyboardFrame = value.cgRectValue

        //TODO: Not animating properly
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(), animations: { () -> Void in
            self.bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height
            }, completion: { Bool -> Void in
            self.textViewScrollToBottom()
        })
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
        // bring the text field back down..
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(), animations: { () -> Void in
            self.bottomConstraint.constant = 0
        }, completion: nil)

    }

    func reloadView() {
        // in case we're the visible view again
        serial.delegate = self

        if serial.isReady {
            navItem.title = serial.connectedPeripheral!.name
            barButton.title = "Disconnect"
            barButton.tintColor = UIColor.red
            barButton.isEnabled = true
        } else if serial.centralManager.state == .poweredOn {
            navItem.title = "Bluetooth Serial"
            barButton.title = "Connect"
            barButton.tintColor = view.tintColor
            barButton.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            navItem.title = "Bluetooth Serial"
            barButton.title = "Connect"
            barButton.tintColor = view.tintColor
            barButton.isEnabled = false
        }
    }

    func textViewScrollToBottom() {
        let range = NSMakeRange(NSString(string: mainTextView.text).length - 1, 1)
        mainTextView.scrollRangeToVisible(range)
        //mainTextView.text = "";
    }


//MARK: BluetoothSerialDelegate

    func serialDidReceiveString(_ message: String) {
        // add the received text to the textView, optionally with a line break at the end
        mainTextView.text! += message
        let pref = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: ReceivedMessageOptionKey)
        if pref == ReceivedMessageOption.newline.rawValue { mainTextView.text! += "\n" }
        textViewScrollToBottom()

    }

    func serialDidDisconnect(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: NSError?) {
        reloadView()
        dismissKeyboard()
        let hud = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: view, animated: true)
        hud?.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.text
        hud?.labelText = "Disconnected"
        hud?.hide(true, afterDelay: 1.0)
    }

    func serialDidChangeState() {
        reloadView()
        if serial.centralManager.state != .poweredOn {
            dismissKeyboard()
            let hud = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: view, animated: true)
            hud?.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.text
            hud?.labelText = "Bluetooth turned off"
            hud?.hide(true, afterDelay: 1.0)
        }
    }


//MARK: UITextFieldDelegate

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if !serial.isReady {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Not connected", message: "What am I supposed to send this to?", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { action -> Void in self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) }))
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            messageField.resignFirstResponder()
            return true
        }

        // send the message to the bluetooth device
        // but fist, add optionally a line break or carriage return (or both) to the message
        let pref = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: MessageOptionKey)
        var msg = messageField.text!
        switch pref {
        case MessageOption.newline.rawValue:
            msg += "\n"
        case MessageOption.carriageReturn.rawValue:
            msg += "\r"
        case MessageOption.carriageReturnAndNewline.rawValue:
            msg += "\r\n"
        default:
            msg += ""
        }

        // send the message and clear the textfield
        serial.sendMessageToDevice(msg)
        messageField.text = ""
        return true
    }

    func dismissKeyboard() {
        messageField.resignFirstResponder()
    }


//MARK: IBActions

    @IBAction func barButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if serial.connectedPeripheral == nil {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowScanner", sender: self)
        } else {
            serial.disconnect()
            reloadView()
        }
    }
}
```

CoreBluetooth Code.

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth
var serial: BluetoothSerial!   // Global serial handler, don't forget to initialize it with init(delgate:)
// Delegate functions
protocol BluetoothSerialDelegate {
// ** Required **

/// Called when de state of the CBCentralManager changes (e.g. when bluetooth is turned on/off)
func serialDidChangeState()

/// Called when a peripheral disconnected
func serialDidDisconnect(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: NSError?)

// ** Optionals **

/// Called when a message is received
func serialDidReceiveString(_ message: String)

/// Called when a message is received
func serialDidReceiveBytes(_ bytes: [UInt8])

/// Called when a message is received
func serialDidReceiveData(_ data: Data)

/// Called when the RSSI of the connected peripheral is read
func serialDidReadRSSI(_ rssi: NSNumber)

/// Called when a new peripheral is discovered while scanning. Also gives the RSSI (signal strength)
func serialDidDiscoverPeripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, RSSI: NSNumber?)

/// Called when a peripheral is connected (but not yet ready for cummunication)
func serialDidConnect(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral)

/// Called when a pending connection failed
func serialDidFailToConnect(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: NSError?)

/// Called when a peripheral is ready for communication
func serialIsReady(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral)
```

}

```
// Make some of the delegate functions optional extension BluetoothSerialDelegate {
func serialDidReceiveString(_ message: String) {}
func serialDidReceiveBytes(_ bytes: [UInt8]) {}
func serialDidReceiveData(_ data: Data) {}
func serialDidReadRSSI(_ rssi: NSNumber) {}
func serialDidDiscoverPeripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, RSSI: NSNumber?) {}
func serialDidConnect(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral) {}
func serialDidFailToConnect(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: NSError?) {}
func serialIsReady(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral) {}
}

final class BluetoothSerial: NSObject,CBCentralManagerDelegate,CBPeripheralDelegate {

// MARK: Variables

/// The delegate object the BluetoothDelegate methods will be called upon
var delegate: BluetoothSerialDelegate!

/// The CBCentralManager this bluetooth serial handler uses for... well, everything really
var centralManager: CBCentralManager!

/// The peripheral we're trying to connect to (nil if none)
var pendingPeripheral: CBPeripheral?

/// The connected peripheral (nil if none is connected)
var connectedPeripheral: CBPeripheral?

/// The characteristic 0xFFE1 we need to write to, of the connectedPeripheral
weak var writeCharacteristic: CBCharacteristic?

/// Whether this serial is ready to send and receive data
var isReady: Bool {
    get {
        return centralManager.state == .poweredOn &&
               connectedPeripheral != nil &&
               writeCharacteristic != nil
    }
}

/// Whether this serial is looking for advertising peripherals
var isScanning: Bool {
    return centralManager.isScanning
}

/// Whether the state of the centralManager is .poweredOn
var isPoweredOn: Bool {
    return centralManager.state == .poweredOn
}

/// UUID of the service to look for.
var serviceUUID = CBUUID(string: "FFE0")

/// UUID of the characteristic to look for.
var characteristicUUID = CBUUID(string: "FFE1")

/// Whether to write to the HM10 with or without response. Set automatically.
/// Legit HM10 modules (from JNHuaMao) require 'Write without Response',
/// while fake modules (e.g. from Bolutek) require 'Write with Response'.
private var writeType: CBCharacteristicWriteType = .withoutResponse


// MARK: functions

/// Always use this to initialize an instance
init(delegate: BluetoothSerialDelegate) {
    super.init()
    self.delegate = delegate
    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
}

/// Start scanning for peripherals
func startScan() {
    guard centralManager.state == .poweredOn else { return }

    // start scanning for peripherals with correct service UUID
    centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [serviceUUID], options: nil)

    // retrieve peripherals that are already connected
    // see this stackoverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286487
    let peripherals = centralManager.retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices: [serviceUUID])
    for peripheral in peripherals {
        delegate.serialDidDiscoverPeripheral(peripheral, RSSI: nil)
    }
}

/// Stop scanning for peripherals
func stopScan() {
    centralManager.stopScan()
}

/// Try to connect to the given peripheral
func connectToPeripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    pendingPeripheral = peripheral
    centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
}

/// Disconnect from the connected peripheral or stop connecting to it
func disconnect() {
    if let p = connectedPeripheral {
        centralManager.cancelPeripheralConnection(p)
    } else if let p = pendingPeripheral {
        centralManager.cancelPeripheralConnection(p) //TODO: Test whether its neccesary to set p to nil
    }
}

/// The didReadRSSI delegate function will be called after calling this function
func readRSSI() {
    guard isReady else { return }
    connectedPeripheral!.readRSSI()
}

/// Send a string to the device
func sendMessageToDevice(_ message: String) {
    guard isReady else { return }

    if let data = message.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        connectedPeripheral!.writeValue(data, for: writeCharacteristic!, type: writeType)
    }
}

/// Send an array of bytes to the device
func sendBytesToDevice(_ bytes: [UInt8]) {
    guard isReady else { return }

    let data = Data(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(bytes), count: bytes.count)
    connectedPeripheral!.writeValue(data, for: writeCharacteristic!, type: writeType)
}

/// Send data to the device
func sendDataToDevice(_ data: Data) {
    guard isReady else { return }

    connectedPeripheral!.writeValue(data, for: writeCharacteristic!, type: writeType)
}


// MARK: CBCentralManagerDelegate functions

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    // just send it to the delegate
    delegate.serialDidDiscoverPeripheral(peripheral, RSSI: RSSI)
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    // set some stuff right
    peripheral.delegate = self
    pendingPeripheral = nil
    connectedPeripheral = peripheral

    // send it to the delegate
    delegate.serialDidConnect(peripheral)

    // Okay, the peripheral is connected but we're not ready yet!
    // First get the 0xFFE0 service
    // Then get the 0xFFE1 characteristic of this service
    // Subscribe to it & create a weak reference to it (for writing later on), 
    // and find out the writeType by looking at characteristic.properties.
    // Only then we're ready for communication

    peripheral.discoverServices([serviceUUID])
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
    connectedPeripheral = nil
    pendingPeripheral = nil

    // send it to the delegate
    delegate.serialDidDisconnect(peripheral, error: error as NSError?)
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
    pendingPeripheral = nil

    // just send it to the delegate
    delegate.serialDidFailToConnect(peripheral, error: error as NSError?)
}

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    // note that "didDisconnectPeripheral" won't be called if BLE is turned off while connected
    connectedPeripheral = nil
    pendingPeripheral = nil

    // send it to the delegate
    delegate.serialDidChangeState()
}


// MARK: CBPeripheralDelegate functions

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
    // discover the 0xFFE1 characteristic for all services (though there should only be one)
    for service in peripheral.services! {
        peripheral.discoverCharacteristics([characteristicUUID], for: service)
    }
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
    // check whether the characteristic we're looking for (0xFFE1) is present - just to be sure
    for characteristic in service.characteristics! {
        if characteristic.uuid == characteristicUUID {
            // subscribe to this value (so we'll get notified when there is serial data for us..)
            peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)

            // keep a reference to this characteristic so we can write to it
            writeCharacteristic = characteristic

            // find out writeType
            writeType = characteristic.properties.contains(.write) ? .withResponse : .withoutResponse

            // notify the delegate we're ready for communication
            delegate.serialIsReady(peripheral)
        }
    }
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    // notify the delegate in different ways
    // if you don't use one of these, just comment it (for optimum efficiency :])
    let data = characteristic.value
    guard data != nil else { return }

    // first the data
    delegate.serialDidReceiveData(data!)

    // then the string
    if let str = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        delegate.serialDidReceiveString(str)
    } else {
        //print("Received an invalid string!") uncomment for debugging
    }

    // now the bytes array
    var bytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: data!.count / MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size)
    (data! as NSData).getBytes(&bytes, length: data!.count)
    delegate.serialDidReceiveBytes(bytes)
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didReadRSSI RSSI: NSNumber, error: Error?) {
    delegate.serialDidReadRSSI(RSSI)
}
```

}

HERE IS THE WHOLE CODE:  https://github.com/vari217/aw

Comment: There is a whole chapter in the Core Bluetooth programming guide on using Bluetooth in the background. You will need your app to implement background mode and post a local notification when the appropriate data is received

Comment: and how to print data/update data in single line ??

Comment: What do you mean in a single line? Do you mean with a single print statement?  Why not simply send your two sensor values separated by a comma and leave it up to the app to make threshold judgements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the value only when you tap in your button, you have to prevent your Arduino to do that once it receives a flag from your BT.

Do NOT use such amount of delay in your main loop, 10 seconds is too much. Figure how to handle events instead of holding your loop, you can have others tasks to work on.

I did not see your whole code, but from what you've posted I would follow this path.

For your Arduino, wait to read and spool until you have a requisition from your app, don't waste cpu time if not in use. 
If you want to buffer some value every each XX seconds, place a routine where you verify sensors every each XX seconds and hold it on your rom (if really need).

If not, my suggestion is:

```
char val;         // variable to receive data from the serial port [BT]
char buffer[50];
void setup()
{

  Serial.begin(115200);       // start serial communication at 115200bps

}

void loop() {

  if( Serial.available() )       // if data is available to read
  {
    val = Serial.read();         // read it and store it in 'val'
  }

  if( val == 'T' )               // if 'T' was received read temperature
  {
    sensorInput = analogRead(A0);    //read the analog sensor and store it
    temp = (double)sensorInput / 1024;       //find percentage of input reading
    temp = temp * 5;                 //multiply by 5V to get voltage
    temp = temp - 0.5;               //Subtract the offset 
    temp = temp * 100;               //Convert to degrees 


    if (temp > 28 ) {

      sprintf(buffer, "Current Temp is hot i.e.: %d", temp);
      Serial.println(buffer);
    }

    else if (temp < 28) {
      sprintf(buffer, "Current Temp is cold i.e.: %d", temp);
      Serial.println(buffer);
    }
    else {
      sprintf(buffer, "Current Temp %d", temp);
      Serial.println(buffer);
    }
  }

  if( val == 'L' )               // if 'L' was received read light 
  {
    sensorValue = analogRead(A1);    //read the analog sensor and store it
    if (sensorValue > 70 ) {
      sprintf(buffer, "Current Light is high i.e.: %d", sensorValue);
      Serial.println(buffer);
    }
    else if (sensorValue < 60) {
      sprintf(buffer, "Current Light is low i.e.: %d", sensorValue);
      Serial.println(buffer);
    }
    else {
      sprintf(buffer, "Light seems good: %d", sensorValue);
      Serial.println(buffer);      
    }
  }
  val = '';
}
```

And for your swift code, something like that:

```
@IBAction func getTemperature(sender: AnyObject)
{
  var str:NSString = "T"
  data = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
  peripheral.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: arrCharacteristics!.objectAtIndex(1) as CBCharacteristic , type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithoutResponse)
}

@IBAction func getLight(sender: AnyObject)
{
  var str:NSString = "L"
  data = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
  peripheral.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: arrCharacteristics!.objectAtIndex(1) as CBCharacteristic , type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithoutResponse)
}
```

For your question about notifications, I would follow @Paulw11's suggestion, there are some pitfalls on iOS background and following a tutorial is the best way you have to achieve it.

For your question about one line print, have a look on `sprintf` function as used in my code.

Comment: thankyou soo much for giving me your time. I will try do what you said after I come from work and let you know. thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help. If my answer helped you just don't forget to accept it as your accepted answer. Thanks

Comment: thanks, your Arduino answer did help me a lot, its straight to the point and very simple. thanks once again. I am still not getting the iPhone one. please can you explain a little, I am new to ios. ---- I have changed your code like below i dont know if its right or not and in the code if I am right than how can i get to know the right character from array

Comment: `var _peripheral: CBPeripheral?
var _characteristics: [CBCharacteristic]?

@IBAction func getTemp(_ sender: Any) {
        var str:NSString = "L"
        let data = str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
        _peripheral.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: arrCharacteristics!.objectAtIndex(1) as CBCharacteristic , type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithoutResponse)

    }`

Comment: What is your `serial = BluetoothSerial(delegate: self)` "serial" type ? It should have write method as it is your BT manager. then you can replace the "peripheral" from my code to "serial". Anyway, you can follow this tutorial which guided me sometime ago when I was working with BT. http://ladvien.github.io/robots/ios-manager/

Comment: this is another very nice and complete example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26377615/ble-swift-write-characterisitc

Comment: hi @GIJOW
 I am still not getting it its a lot hard than I thought. Its the one last thing i need for my an app and it seems like after a reaching long way I still have nothing. please help me in this. I have attached my core bluetooth code above in the question. I think you were talking about it in your previous answer. if I am correct than after changing the "peripheral" from your code to the serial it still gives an error regarding "arrCharacteristics" error is --  "Use of unresolved identifier 'arrCharacteristics'"  please help

Comment: I'll have a look and make a test project here

Comment: It would be really helpful if I complete this app somehow as it will also be able help me in future projects and will be a great tutorial for me.

Comment: Hi friend, I really do not understand. I've downloaded your project and there is a function sendMessageToDevice ready to go in your file BluetoothSerial.swift, it waits a string as parameter so everything is done

Comment: is there a way to send the command like the keybord does because if I type "L" in the app keybord it gives the result I want. I just dont know how to do it through button.

Comment: just attach a button in you SerialViewController and call serial.sendMessageToDevice('L'). Over and out. Good luck